# Speed of FPGA fabric

Tags: fpga

What limits the speed of FPGA fabric to Mhz range, while CPU pipelines are clocked much faster? Is it the interconnect delays that places a limit on signal timing?

Comment: Yes, a line which transmits the signal from A to B is much faster than a line which can transmit the same signal from A to about anywhere else in the chip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reconfigurability comes at a steep price. Logic cells in FPGAs are complex, making them much slower than the equivalent (but not reconfigurable) hard logic on an ASIC. Routing between logic cells requires long wires and pass gates, both of which increase parasitic resistance and capacitance, slowing signal propagation.